# Textbooks about integration w.r.t. signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, signed-measures

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058578/integration-with-respect-to-sum-of-signed-measures) question about signed measure.  Assume that $\lambda$ is a finite signed measure and have a Jordan decomposition $\lambda = \lambda^+ - \lambda^-$. Then
$$
\int f \mathrm d \lambda := \int f \mathrm d \lambda^+ - \int f \mathrm d \lambda^-,
$$
if both integrals are finite.

However, I could not find a textbook that define integration with respect to a sign measure. Could you please suggest me some textbook references?

Comment: As you wrote, integration w.r.t. the signed measure is reduced to integration w.r.t. two nonnegative measures. What do we need an entire text book for ?

Comment: @KurtG. I'm writing a report to my professors, so I'm looking for an official reference and for more information.

Comment: Please try this : https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=signed+measures

Comment: @Akira Folland's book "Real analysis" does this. There really is not much to say though, because integration with respect to signed measures boils down to integration of positive measures.